# I'm looking geometry code and I don't know p1[X] code

Tags: c, struct, geometry, typedef, point

```
typedef struct {
   double a; // coefficient for x
   double b; // coefficient for y
   double c; // constant term
} line;

points_to_line(point p1, point p2, line *l)
{
   if (p1[X] == p2[X]) {
      l->a = 1;
      l->b = 0;
      l->c = -p1[X];
} else {
      l->b = 1;
      l->a = -(p1[Y]-p2[Y])/(p1[X]-p2[X]);
      l->c = -(l->a * p1[X]) - (l->b * p1[Y]);
}
```

I'm reading Programming Challenges book by (Steven S. Skiena and Miguel Revilla), maybe someone should have been read this book.

p1[X] is point p1's X value, and [Y] is Y value.

This function makes a linear equation line. (`line *l`)
First If sentense makes `x + C (p1[X]) = 0` to l.

What I don't know is:

- In C language, how can I represent `p1[X]`??
- Is `p1` a one dimentional array? then, `X` and `Y` is constant macro??
- Or, using C++, Is this a overloaded operator[] ?? then, point type has overloaded operator[]???
- Or is there point type in C?? I searched google "point type C" and, I found nothing.

Comment: The answers to your questions should be in the book. Since C doesn't have a built in `point` type, the author of the book would have defined it earlier on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it is C code, as `p1` is accessed with `[]` operator, my guess is `point` type is likely to be a `typedef` to an array.

```
#define X  0
#define Y  1
typedef double point[2];
```

I think it is `double` because `(p1[Y]-p2[Y])/(p1[X]-p2[X])` expression is written without `double` casts.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, it's likely that this is C and a header contains:

```
typedef double point[2];
enum { X, Y };
```

or rather than the enum, it could be

```
#define X 0
#define Y 1
```

However, this is not the best code.  The 2-point line equation is

(x - x1) / (y - y1) = (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1)

Cross multiplying:

(x - x1) (y2 - y1) = (y - y1) (x2 - x1)

x (y2 - y1) - y (x2 - x1) - x1 (y2 - y1) + y1 (x2 - x1) = 0

So we can just use

a = y2 - y1, b = x1 - x2, c = - x1 a - y1 b

or in code

```
l->a = p2[Y] - p1[Y];
l->b = p1[X] - p2[X];
l->c = - p1[X] * l->a - p1[Y] * l->b;
```

This way there is no need to check for zero.

Answer (score 1):

The structure `point` needs to be defined, similar to the `typedef` that defines `line`. I would set it up like this:

```
typedef struct {
  double X; 
  double Y; 
} point;
```

With that structure, you can access `X` of `p1` as `p1.X`.

Another option is given in [ouah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10910175/22114), he just defines a point as an array with the size of 2, in that case you would access `X` as `p1[0]`, and `Y` as `p1[1]` - **if x is the first, and y is the second value in your array. This is not explicitly stated in the code!** It is very easy to mix things up and write `p1[1]` (accessing `Y`) when what you really wanted is to access `X`. I think the array approach is much more prone to cause errors in the code, which is why I would **always** take the time to write two more lines, as I did in the `typedef` above.

In my example, you use the point operator to access a specific variable of a structure. In ouah's example, you use [] (is that an operator? probably, but I'm not certain) to access the elements inside the array. Note that in C & Co, the first element is addressed with the index 0, the second with 1, the 3rd with 2 etc.